# Access option and argument with same name

Tags: expl3

I'm trying to understand the scope of variables in latex3 and to construct an example of a function that takes an option and an argument of a command both (option and argument) having the same name.

Note: I explicitly use the same name in the example to find out and learn about the scope of variables.

**Update**: *I am aware that I am using the same name for two different things. This is on purpose. The reason here is to be able to test and learn which parts are encapsulated and which ones are not. AFAICS there is some kind encapsulation within `group_begin` and `group_end`. This encapsulation seems also to propagate to the functions called within a group. But it seems to me that within `keys_define` there is no encapsulation.*

*In the call of `\mycommand[name=optionname]{name=argname}` we can use the same name for two different things. Is this possible in two different `keys_define` at all? If not, what is the technical reason?*

*From the perspective of other programming languages I'm searching for something like `mymodule_myoptions::l_mymodule_name_tl` and `mymodule_myargs::l_mymodule_name_tl`.*

In my example I want to call `\mycommand[name=optionname]{name=argname}` that `keys_set`s the options and arguments to its respective `keys_define` and call a function `\__mymodule_ShowOptionsAndArgs:nn #1 #2` with the option `name` (as #1) and the argument `name` (as #2) and this function should output both `option=optionname; arg=argname`.

The example below outputs the following (see also comments in code):

```
option=initoptionname; arg=initargname
option=optionname;     arg=initargname
option=initoptionname; arg=argname
option=initoptionname; arg=initargname
```

How should I change my example to get

```
option=optionname; arg=argname
```

How can I do this? What are best practives?

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { mymodule / myoptions }
  { 
    name .tl_set:N = \l_mymodule_name_tl,
  }

\keys_define:nn { mymodule / myargs }
  { 
    name .tl_set:N = \l_mymodule_name_tl,
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mymodule_ShowOptionsAndArgs:nn #1 #2
  {
    \par option = #1 ;~ arg = #2
  }
```

```latex
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mymodule_myfunction:nn #1#2
  {
    \tl_new:N \l_optionname_tl
    \tl_new:N \l_argname_tl
    \tl_set:Nn \l_optionname_tl { initoptionname }
    \tl_set:Nn \l_argname_tl { initargname }

    \__mymodule_ShowOptionsAndArgs:nn { \l_optionname_tl } { \l_argname_tl }
    % -> option=initoptionname; arg=initargname
    \group_begin:
      \keys_set:nn { mymodule / myoptions } { #1 }
      \tl_set:Nn \l_optionname_tl { \l_mymodule_name_tl }
      \__mymodule_ShowOptionsAndArgs:nn { \l_optionname_tl } { \l_argname_tl }
      % -> option=optionname; arg=initargname
    \group_end:

    \group_begin:
      \keys_set:nn { mymodule / myargs } { #2 }
      \tl_set:Nn \l_argname_tl { \l_mymodule_name_tl }
      \__mymodule_ShowOptionsAndArgs:nn { \l_optionname_tl } { \l_argname_tl }
      % -> option=initoptionname; arg=argname
    \group_end:

    \__mymodule_ShowOptionsAndArgs:nn { \l_optionname_tl } { \l_argname_tl }
    % -> option=initoptionname; arg=initargname
  }
```

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{ o m }
  {
    \__mymodule_myfunction:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\mycommand[name=optionname]{name=argname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: why are you using `\l_mymodule_name_tl,`  to store two different things?  if you remove all the expl3 and keyval stuff you have `\def\aaa{A}  \def\aaa{B}`  then wonder why the second over-writes the first.  also `\tl_new:N \l_optionname_tl` should be at the top level not inside your function, it won't be new the second time.

Comment: Could you explain what you expect and why? Is the output you describe what you get or what you want to get? First you say it is what you get, but then you ask how to get it. If I run your code, I (1) get the output you give and (2) that output is what I'd expect, so it isn't clear what you want to know.

Comment: \@DavidCarlisle \@cfr Please see my update.

Comment: it's not really clear what you want here, possibly there is too much code to guess what you expect it to do. tex is a macro language, there is no scope implied by a macro call itself whether expl3 or \newcommand   or \def. scope is just via explicit group begin and group end, at which point every local assignment within the group is restored.  So `\def\x{a} { \def\x{b} ...}  \x`  then `\x` is `a` at the end as its value is restored at the `}`.  all the expl3 and keyval syntax does not change this fundamental tex behaviour.

Comment: This is completely unlike a compiled language where there are functions which have function-local variables.

Comment: \@DavidCarlisle. You're right. From the perspective of other programming languages it is not obvious.

Comment: I wonder why there is a `\keys_if_exist:nnTF { mymodule/myoptions } { name } { <function> } { <function2> }` for testing the existence of the key internally stored under `mymodule/myoptions/name` but no function to access the value of the key `mymodule/myoptions/name`. Does l3keys itself not store the values under the keys? But delegates storing the value to the given variable? Maybe is this what is confusing me.

Comment: If this is the case, then it means that there are two different keys `mymodule/myoptions/name` and `mymodule/myargs/name` both storing the value into the same variable `\l_optionname_tl`?

Comment: @wolfrevo Keys don't take values in general. Most of them do, but `keyname .code:n ={}` executes code. It may or may not take a value, but, if it does, it is because the definition of `keyname` does something with it.

Comment: @wolfrevo Yes. You have two different keys storing values in the same variable. They therefore overwrite one another.

Comment: @wolfrevo It's not just other programming languages, I don't think. The behaviour you're describing sounds similar to `pgfkeys`. There, you can say `/keyname/.initial={value}` and `{value}` is stored in `keyname`. But that's not how `l3keys` is setup. From a LaTeX perspective, this ends up rather complicated and I don't find it very intuitive, but maybe the similarity with other languages explains why it was designed this way.

Comment: \@cfr yes. Something similar I've tested parsing with `\keyval_parse` and passing the kevals to a property list (`l3prop`).

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand: there is no need for paraphernalia like in my example since the same single variable is merely used by two different keys. Thank you both \@DavidCarlisle \@cfr for your patience with my example(s).

Answer (score 1):

Variables, control sequences, commands, macros ... these things can all be defined or redefined either locally or globally. If a change is local, it's influence is contained within the current TeX group.

Indefinitely many different syntax variations/commands can be used to begin and end groups, depending on the context. The following list is intended only to illustrate some of the most common constructions. In each case the '...' represents a local group. Local changes made within this group have no effect after the end of the group.

- `\group_begin:` ... `\group_end:` (`expl3`)
- `\group` ... `\endgroup` (TeX)
- `{` ... `}` where the braces (curly brackets) aren't doing something like containing an argument. For example, `\section{Section}` doesn't create a group because the `{` and `}` are just delimiting the argument.
- `\begin{<environment>}` ... `\end{<environment>}` (LaTeX 2e)

If you want a change to persist after the end of the current group, you have to make it globally. If you want a change to influence only the current group, you should make it locally.

In `expl3`, variables should be used as either local or global and their names should indicate this.

- `\l_<module>_<description>_<type>` should be set only locally using, for example `\tl_set:Nn` for a token list.
- `\g_<module>_<description>_<type>` should be set only globally using, for example `\tl_gset:Nn` for a token list.

A variable such as `\l_mymodule_name_tl` or `\g_mymodule_name_tl` cannot be used for two different token lists at the same time. If you need to capture two distinct token lists at the same time, you need two variables.

Since you want each of the `name` keys to set a token list variable to a different token list and to access these two distinct token lists at the same time, you cannot use the same token list variable for both keys. Instead, you need something like

```
\keys_define:nn { mymodule / myoptions }
  { 
    name .tl_set:N = \l_mymodule_myoptions_name_tl,
  }

\keys_define:nn { mymodule / myargs }
  { 
    name .tl_set:N = \l_mymodule_myargs_name_tl,
  }
```

But if you want the changes to persist after `\group_end:`, you'd need to use global rather than local variables with `\tl_gset:Nn` rather than `\tl_set:Nn`.

Consider

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \g_optionname_tl
\tl_new:N \g_argname_tl
\tl_gset:Nn \g_optionname_tl { initoptionname }
\tl_gset:Nn \g_argname_tl { initargname }

\keys_define:nn { mymodule / myoptions }
  { 
    name .tl_set:N = \l_mymodule_myoptions_name_tl,
  }
\keys_define:nn { mymodule / myargs }
  { 
    name .tl_set:N = \l_mymodule_myargs_name_tl,
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mymodule_ShowOptionsAndArgs:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
  {
    \par option = #1 ;~ arg = #2 ; ~ oname = #3 ; ~ aname = #4
  }
  \cs_generate_variant:Nn \__mymodule_ShowOptionsAndArgs:nnnn { VVVV }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mymodule_myfunction:nn #1#2
  {
    \__mymodule_ShowOptionsAndArgs:VVVV  \g_optionname_tl  \g_argname_tl \l_mymodule_myoptions_name_tl \l_mymodule_myargs_name_tl
    % -> option=initoptionname; arg=initargname
    \group_begin:
      \keys_set:nn { mymodule / myoptions } { #1 }
      \tl_gset:NV \g_optionname_tl \l_mymodule_myoptions_name_tl 
      \__mymodule_ShowOptionsAndArgs:VVVV  \g_optionname_tl  \g_argname_tl \l_mymodule_myoptions_name_tl \l_mymodule_myargs_name_tl
      % -> option=optionname; arg=initargname
    \group_end:    

    \group_begin:
      \keys_set:nn { mymodule / myargs } { #2 }
      \tl_gset:NV \g_argname_tl  \l_mymodule_aname_tl 
      \__mymodule_ShowOptionsAndArgs:VVVV  \g_optionname_tl  \g_argname_tl \l_mymodule_myoptions_name_tl \l_mymodule_myargs_name_tl
      % -> option=optionname; arg=argname
    \group_end:

    \__mymodule_ShowOptionsAndArgs:VVVV  \g_optionname_tl  \g_argname_tl \l_mymodule_myoptions_name_tl \l_mymodule_myargs_name_tl
    % -> option=optionname; arg=argname
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{ o m }
  {
    \__mymodule_myfunction:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\mycommand[name=optionname]{name=argname}
\end{document}
```

The keys set `\l_mymodule_myoptions_name_tl` and `\l_mymodule_myargs_name_tl` locally, but we use the values to set `\g_optionname_tl` and `\g_argname_tl` globally. A further difference is that the local variables are initially empty, whereas the global ones are not.

[image: effects of global vs. local changes]

Note that the global changes accumulate, regardless of `\group_begin:` etc., whereas the local ones disappear at `\group_end:`.

Comment: \@cfr Not really asking about grouping. See my update.

Comment: @wolfrevo It's `\l_mymodule_name_tl` which is problematic. You can't use this for two different things at the same time.

Comment: @wolfrevo What should the final use of the command output? The initial values or something else? You say you're not asking about grouping, but your update mentions 'encapsulation' be `\group_begin: ... \group_end:`, which is grouping.

Comment: @wolfrevo See updated answer above. I'm still not convinced this is what you're asking, but perhaps it will help somebody figure that out.

Comment: Thanks the example is really useful for understanding grouping and `tl_(g)set`. Although it uses two different variable names `\l_mymodule_oname_tl` and `\l_mymodule_aname_tl` which of course is mandatory since otherwise (as explained above) the variable would be overwritten by the different keys.

Comment: For variable names used by `keys_define` I'd suggest to extend the naming convention as to include the subgroup. E.g. `\keys_define:nn { module / subgroup } { name .tl_set:N = \l_module_subgroup_name_tl }`

Comment: @wolfrevo Exactly. I mean, you can have two keys setting the same variable if you like, but it will be the same variable.

Comment: @wolfrevo I agree (see edit). I wasn't sure if I was even answering your question, so I didn't take much care with the naming. Usually, this is indeed a good idea. But if you want the *convention* changed, you'll have to lobby David et al.!

Comment: It's perfectly reasonable to have two keys set the same variable: imagine for example you don't want to punish UK English speakers so have `color` and `colour` ;)

Comment: @JosephWright There are other cases where it makes sense, too. But doesn't it have to be either a case where you want the two keys to set the same thing or a case where you don't want to use the keys at the same time?

Comment: @JosephWright That is, you can use two keys for the same thing by having them set the same variable. Or you can use two keys for different things by using them at different times with the same variable. But you can't use one variable for two things at the same time.

Comment: @JosephWright Maybe the referents of 'things' was unclear?

Comment: Or maybe I should just delete it now the OP has answered.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with the underlying concepts and thanks to the valuable comments posted here I came up with a possible solution of my question. The approach is realized using a property list and let `keys_define` add its keys "prefixed" with the name of the subgroup:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \l_mypropertylist
\keys_define:nn { mymodule / options }
  { name .code:n = \prop_put:Nnn \l_mypropertylist { options / name } {#1}, }
\keys_define:nn { mymodule / args }
  { name .code:n = \prop_put:Nnn \l_mypropertylist { args / name } {#1}, }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mymodule_DoSomethingWithBothNameVariables:nn #1 #2
  { \par option = #1 ;~ arg = #2 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mymodule_myfunction:nn #1#2
  {
    \keys_set:nn { mymodule / options } { #1 }
    \keys_set:nn { mymodule / args } { #2 }
    \prop_map_function:NN \l_mypropertylist \msg_show_item:nn
    \__mymodule_DoSomethingWithBothNameVariables:nn 
      { \prop_item:Nn \l_mypropertylist { options / name } }
      { \prop_item:Nn \l_mypropertylist { args / name } }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{ o m }
  { \__mymodule_myfunction:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\mycommand[name=optionname]{name=argname}
\end{document}
```

The output is

```
> {options/name} => {optionname}
> {args/name} => {argname}
option=optionname; arg=argname
```

**Update**: *One of the advantages/features of such an approach is that the "state" of the module (i.e. the current values of the options and arguments) can be easily accessed/reported at any time with e.g. `\prop_map_function:NN \l_mypropertylist <function>`. This is one feature/enhancement that I miss in `l3keys`: to report and access the current status of the keys defined. AFAIK `l3keys` only offers `\l_keys_path_str`, `\l_keys_key_str`, and `\l_keys_value_tl` which store only the last processed key.*

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149415/discussion-on-answer-by-wolfrevo-access-option-and-argument-with-same-name); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.